# How to Separate and Align Boxes: From Flexbox to Grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a problem with the alignment and separation of the boxes.

In the image you can see that one box is completely stuck with another.

And the CSS code I think is correct.

With the responsive design I have the problem that the boxes are not aligned in the center.

Shall anybody help me?

[image]

I copy the code.

Thanks!!

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Maquetación con Flexbox </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

    <!--Inicio container-->
    <div id="container">
        <!--Inicio cabecera-->
        <header id="header">
            <div class="logo">
                <h1> Portafolio</h1>
            </div>

            <nav id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Inicio</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Proyectos</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Blog</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contacto</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

        </header>
        <!--Fin cabecera-->

        <!--Incio contenido-->
        <section id="content">
            <aside id="aside">
                <h2>¿Que quieres ver?</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Webs</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Apps</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Diseños</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Otros</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </aside>

            <div id="projects">
                <article class="project">
                    <div class="image-wrap">
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x180"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="project-info">
                        <a href="#">Nombre proyecto</a>
                        <p>Sitio web</p>
                    </div>
                </article>

                <article class="project">
                    <div class="image-wrap">
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x180"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="project-info">
                        <a href="#">Nombre proyecto</a>
                        <p>Sitio web</p>
                    </div>
                </article>

                <article class="project">
                    <div class="image-wrap">
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x180"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="project-info">
                        <a href="#">Nombre proyecto</a>
                        <p>Sitio web</p>
                    </div>
                </article>

                <article class="project">
                    <div class="image-wrap">
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x180"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="project-info">
                        <a href="#">Nombre proyecto</a>
                        <p>Sitio web</p>
                    </div>
                </article>

                <article class="project">
                    <div class="image-wrap">
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x180"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="project-info">
                        <a href="#">Nombre proyecto</a>
                        <p>Sitio web</p>
                    </div>
                </article>

                <article class="project">
                    <div class="image-wrap">
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x180"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="project-info">
                        <a href="#">Nombre proyecto</a>
                        <p>Sitio web</p>
                    </div>
                </article>

                <article class="project">
                    <div class="image-wrap">
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x180"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="project-info">
                        <a href="#">Nombre proyecto</a>
                        <p>Sitio web</p>
                    </div>
                </article>

                <article class="project">
                    <div class="image-wrap">
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x180"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="project-info">
                        <a href="#">Nombre proyecto</a>
                        <p>Sitio web</p>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>

        </section>
        <!--Fin contenido-->

        <footer id="footer">
            <div class="logo">
                Portafolio
            </div>

            <div class="info">
                Cristina Martínez - Web &copy;
            </div>
        </footer>

    </div>
    <!--Fin container-->
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
*{
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

#container{
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border: 1px solid rgba(225, 225, 226, 0.8);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #cccccc;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;

    min-height: 600px;
}

#header{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 65% 30%;
    align-items: center;


    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(225, 225, 226, 0.8);
}

.logo{
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 900px;
    font-size: 35px;

    
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    color: black;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #cccccc;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.logo h1{
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 900px;
    font-size: 35px;
}

#menu{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

#menu > ul{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;

    list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

#menu a{
    color: #444444;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 15px;
    transition: all 300ms;
}

#menu a:hover{
    background: #cccccc;
    color: white;
}

#content{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 20% 1fr;
    align-items: start;
    grid-column-gap: 7px;

    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#projects{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 220px);
    grid-gap: 20px;
    align-items: start;
}

.project{
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    width: 250px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.project img{
    width: 100%;
}

.project-info{
    padding: 10px;
}

.project-info a{
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
    transition: all 300ms;
}

.project-info a:hover{
    color: blue;
}

.project-info p{
    font-size: 16px;
    color: grey;
}

#aside{
    margin-right: 30px;
    padding: 15px;*/
}

#aside h2{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #444444;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(225, 225, 226, 0.8);
    text-align: center;
}

#aside ul{
    list-style: none;
}

#aside ul li{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#aside a{
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #eeeeee;
    color: #444444;
    transition: all 300ms;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#aside a:hover{
    background: #444444;
    color: #eeeeee;
}

#footer{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 25%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: start;

    height: 120px;
    align-items: center;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(225, 225, 226, 0.8);;
}

#footer .logo{
    opacity: 0.5;

    text-align: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#footer .info{
    margin-left: 20px;
    color: #444444;
}

@media (max-width: 784px){
    #header{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 140px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    }

    #header h1{
        text-align: center;
    }

    #content{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        align-items: start;
        grid-column-gap: auto;
    }
    
    #projects{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        grid-gap: 20px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    .project{
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    #aside{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 15px;
    }

    #aside ul{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat (4, 1fr);
        grid-gap: 10px;
    }

    #footer{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center !important;
    }

    #footer .logo{
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside @media (max-width: 784px) change the class project to

```
 .project{
        margin: auto;
 }
```

to center the project when the width of screen is less than 784px.

Comment: The sidebar does not stay vertically up, I suppose it may be from the browser used, in this case, Google Chrome